# Is this fact about matrices and linear systems true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $m$-by-$n$ matrix and $B=A^TA$. If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then $Bx=0$ has a unique solution.

If is true, can you help me prove it? If is false, could you give a counterexample?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If $Bx=0$, then $x^T B x = (Ax)^T (Ax) = \|Ax\|^2 = 0$. Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, $Ax=0$ iff $x=0$. Hence $x=0$ and the solution to $Bx=0$ is not just unique, it is zero.

Comment: Why $Ax=0$ iff $x=0$? Here, $A$ is not square. Does this proposition still holds in this case?

Comment: If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$. (View it as $\sum_k [A]_{\cdot j} x_j = 0$.)

Comment: Even if $A$ is not square, $A^TA$ is square, as it is regardless of $A$'s dimensions.

Comment: If we replace $Bx=0$ by $Bx=b\neq 0$, it is possible to ensure unique solution?

Comment: Yes, it is. Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, $A^TA$ is nonsingular (invertible).

Comment: @VedranŠego Can you explain how is a proof of this?

Comment: Assume that there are two solutions, i.e., $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $Bx_1 = Bx_2 = b$. Then $0 = b - b = Bx_1 - Bx_2 = B(x_1-x_2)$. But, copper.hat proved that this means that $x_1-x_2 = 0$, so $x_1 = x_2$. That's why this kind of things is always enough to prove only for zero.

Answer (score 0):

(Still bogus)

My previous answer was bogus indeed, here is a counterexample :

If $A=  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} = 0 $

Comment: Notice that $A$ is not square.

Comment: $B=A^T A$ not $A A^T$. $A^T A$ is indeed invertible (in fact, it is the identity).

Comment: Sorry, I learned the opposite notation for transposes. But it doesn't matter, I only have to replace A by its transpose, i will edit to reflext this.

Comment: @justt These **columns** are not linearly independent.

Comment: You're right, I got mixed up, sorry. These transposes always confuse me, my teachers (in France) usually write $^{t}A$. Is $A^{T}$ accepted as a standard (at least here on ME)?