# Can we conclude that this matrix is definite positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\text{-by-}m$ matrix. Suppose that columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Can we conclude that $A^TA$ is definite positive? Could you help me with proof?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the third time you've posted essentially the same question! Come on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^m$,
$$
 \langle \xi, A^T A \xi \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^m} = \langle A \xi, A \xi \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n} = \|A \xi \|^2_{\mathbb{R}^n}.
$$
Now:

1. What do you know about the sign of $\|A \xi \|^2_{\mathbb{R}^n}$?
2. Given that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, when is it possible for $\|A \xi \|^2_{\mathbb{R}^n} = 0$?

Comment: if columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then are its rows linearly independent?

Comment: The columns of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are linearly independent, but the rows most certainly are not!

Comment: Very good example. (1) We know $\parallel A \xi\parallel ^2_{\mathbb{R}^n}\geq0 $. (2) $\parallel A\xi\parallel ^2_{\mathbb{R}^n}=0 $ is possible if, and only if, $A\xi=0$ (but here I'm not using the linearly independence). What is the next step?

Comment: So you know that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. What does this imply about the nullspace of $A$?

Comment: But seriously, see @copper.hat's answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424031/is-this-fact-about-matrices-and-linear-systems-true